# Override a function only if a condition is met

Tags: kotlin

I want to have something like this:

```
class ItemBase(private val TOOLTIP: String) : Item(Settings().group(EnderIO.ENDERIO)) {
    fun check() {
        if (TOOLTIP.isNotBlank()) {
            override fun appendTooltip(itemStack: ItemStack?, world: World?, tooltip: MutableList<Text?>, tooltipContext: TooltipContext?) {
                tooltip.add(TranslatableText(TOOLTIP))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to override the function `appendTooltip` only if `TOOLTIP` is not empty.

Comment: What about always override, but your custom action is only executed if the condition is met?

Comment: I can't, the `AppendTooltip` function is from a library

Comment: Uh, why not? If condition is not met, call the super function, for all intent and purpose it's as if it's not overriden

Comment: @Hunam That's what the `super` keyword is for.

Comment: Can you please send me what it would look like in code (I'm a Kotlin beginner)?

Comment: @Hunam When would `check()` be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm not a Kotlin user, so my syntax is probably wrong - but the same prinicples apply to any OOP language):

Kotlin still uses the JVM and the JVM has its own virtual-call system which doesn't support *runtime dispatch* like as you describe - but this isn't a feature that's needed because you can just add the guard statement (i.e. the `if` check) inside the override and then call the `super` version when appropriate. This is one of the most basic and fundamental parts of OOP and is a feature in every single OOP language out there.

Basically, do this:

```
class ItemBase(
    private val TOOLTIP: String
) : Item( Settings().group( EnderIO.ENDERIO ) ) {

    override fun appendTooltip( itemStack: ItemStack?, world: World?, tooltip: MutableList<Text?>, tooltipContext: TooltipContext? ) {

        if( TOOLTIP.isNotBlank() ) {
            super.appendTooltip( itemStack, world, tooltip, tooltipContext )
        }
        else {
            tooltip.add( TranslatableText( TOOLTIP ) )
        }


    }
}
```

### UPDATE:

I think I see that you actually intend for the `check` method to do something like this:

```
class ItemBase(
    private var appendTooltipOverridden: Boolean
    private val TOOLTIP: String
) : Item( Settings().group( EnderIO.ENDERIO ) ) {

    fun check() {
        if( this.TOOLTIP.isNotBlank() ) {
            this.appendTooltipOverridden = true;
        }
    }

    override fun appendTooltip( itemStack: ItemStack?, world: World?, tooltip: MutableList<Text?>, tooltipContext: TooltipContext? ) {

        if( this.appendTooltipOverridden ) {
            tooltip.add( TranslatableText( TOOLTIP ) )

        }
        else {
            // Pass-through to the base implementation:
            super.appendTooltip( itemStack, world, tooltip, tooltipContext )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `check` method was just me trying to get this working.
I don't want to add an other parameter to the class.
I want only on parameter, a string, I want to detect if this string is empty, then, if the string is not empty override the function and if not, do NOTHING.

Comment: Do you have an idea @Dai ?

Comment: @Hunam My first example does that though. What don't you understand about it? Do you understand how the `super` call works?